# Mystery plant misidentified as dragonfruit

Tags: identification, houseplants

Is it even a house plant? It was labeled as "florist" on the price tag so the staff weren't so sure about its' origins and suggested that it might be a dragonfruit or similarly related plant.

-I did prick it to see if it bled white sap like some Euphorbias, but it didn't bleed at all.
[image: Mystery Plant Dragonfruit]

Comment: I am dying to find out what this is as well.  Too weird, a succulent/cactus with 'real' leaves?

Answer (score 2):

It is Cissus quadrangularis, a type of succulent often grown by cactus lovers, though it's actually a member of the grape family (Vitaceae).  It produces these ivy like leaves at certain times, which it uses to try to climb or scramble over surrounding objects or plants. Does well in a hanging basket, when most of its growth will dangle downwards. Tolerates a fair bit of neglect, likes some sun, but more detailed instructions for care here https://www.logees.com/indoor/windowsill/veldt-grape-cissus-quadrangularis.html. Common names include Devil's backbone and veldt grape.

In maturity, it produces small yellow flowers followed by berry like fruits which turn red.

This plant is used medicinally and extracts from it in pill or powder form are often used by people with torn muscles or musculo skeletal damage, and in ayurvedic medicine. There's a fun blog about this plant here http://plantsarethestrangestpeople.blogspot.co.uk/2008/08/infomercial-pitchman-cissus.html

Comment: Really? That's pretty cool. I wouldn't have suspected it'd be a member of the grape family!

Comment: Yea, weird isn't it...doesn't seem possible, but apparently, it is!

Comment: Wait, if it's in the grape family it's NOT a cactus. It lacks areoles which all in the Cactaceae family have. Areoles are not optional in the cactus club. It is also an Old World native, which also excludes it. In actual cactus the spines are modified leaves and the tubercles are modified leaf stems. They do not have vascular leaves, ever.

Comment: This is NOT a cactus. I don't know why my previous detailed comment didn't appear. A plant cannot be in two plant families at once. If it's a grape, it's a grape. It can't be part time in two families.

Comment: @TimNevins I assume you voted my answer down, despite its accuracy. I suggest you read the links I provided - although its called a cactus, it is really a succulent, and is indeed a member of the grape family, I'm not making it up. Still not happy? Then read this  http://www.columbuscactusclub.com/cissus-quadrangularis.html

Comment: For the purists among us, I have altered the answer to reflect the fact that the use of the term  'cactus' (with a small C) does not mean it is a member of Cactaceae. Even though that should have been apparent from the clear statement that it belongs to the Vitaceae...

Comment: I think you were fine prior to the edit, and sticklers being sticklers.

Comment: It was clear you labeled it as a cactus. A cactus is a cactus, things that aren't cactus are not cactus. Just because a cactus club in Cleveland includes it on their site doesn't make it a cactus Even they don't call it a cactus. Four of the six images on their site banner are NOT cactus. Secondly, they specifically state that the plant in question is native to Asia, Malaysia and tropical Africa. That's not where cactus come from. Cactus are exclusively native to the New World. https://www.britannica.com/plant/cactus

Comment: @TimNevins - yes, I already know all that - it gets described as a 'cactus' even though its not a proper Cactus. I hope you're mollified by my further edit today...

Answer (score 0):

"Cissus quadrangularis"

Scientific classification

1. Kingdom: Plantae
2. Clade: Angiosperms
3. Clade: Eudicots
4. Clade: Rosids
5. Order: Vitales
6. Family: Vitaceae
7. Genus: Cissus
8. Species: C. quadrangularis

> Cissus quadrangularis is a perennial plant of the grape family. It is also known as veld grape, devil's backbone, adamant creeper, asthisamharaka, hadjod, pirandai, and patah tulang (Malay).[Wikipedia](http://Wikipedia)

Description:

> A perennial herbaceous climber. Stem thick, succulent, quadrangular, angles winged, constricted at nodes, glabrous or slightly downy, almost leafless when old. Tendril long, slender, simple. Petiole 6-12 mm long, glabrous. Leaves simple ovate, entire or cordate, serrulate dentate, or crenate-serrate, 3-lobed, terminal lobe triangular or sub-spathulate, subacute or ± cuspidate, membranous, glabrous on both sides, 3-5 x 5-3 cm; stipules ovate or cuneate, obtuse, deciduous. Inflorescence a compound umbelliform cymes, peduncle 1-2.5 cm long. Flower pink and white, 2 mm long, hypanthium cuplike, truncate or obsurely lobed, green, c. 2 mm broad. Petals 4,distinct, ovate-oblong, acute, hooded at apex, c. 1.5 mm long. Disc longer than the ovary. Ovary glabrous, style slender subulate, stigma small. Berry globose, red, succulent, very acidic, 6-10 mm in diameter, 1 seeded. Seed obovoid smooth, 4-8 mm across.[Indian science publication](http://eol.org/pages/2880476/details)

Comment: I haven't seen a picture of one flowering or covered in berries. I now wonder what the flowers would smell like and can't wait for my little backbone to get to that stage!